# Changing default SKScene

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

I have a class called IntroLayer I'm trying to load as the inital scene when my game is launched. However after simply changing the GameScene to IntroScene as described in these simple steps, my IntroScene isn't being loaded. I set breakpoints on if let scene to see that it skips over it, and even set breakpoints in the actual IntroScene to verify didMoveToView is not being called. Any ideas?

**I changed the let scene from GameScene to IntroScene in the GameViewController like so:**

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let scene = IntroScene(fileNamed:"IntroScene") {
            // Configure the view.
            let skView = self.view as! SKView
            skView.showsFPS = true
            skView.showsNodeCount = true

            /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
            return .AllButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return .All
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

**Then renamed GameScene.swift to IntroScene.swift and changed the class to this:**

```
import SpriteKit

class IntroScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()


        let fadeIn:SKAction = SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(1.0)
        let fadeOut:SKAction = SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(1.0)




        let inspiredText = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Dead Kansas")
        inspiredText.alpha = 0.0
        inspiredText.text = "Inspired By"
        inspiredText.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        addChild(inspiredText)



        inspiredText.runAction(fadeIn)

    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
       /* Called when a touch begins */

        for touch in touches {
//            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)


        }
    }

}
```

However when I launch the app, it doesn't appear that IntroScene is even called when I set breakpoints, and I'm getting a screen with a gray background.

Comment: did you change the name of the file to IntroScene.swift

Comment: nevermind just read that now

Comment: Yes. I've even tried to replace it with other scenes, it seems none are called / it keeps skipping the "if let scene " as if it's nil or something?

Comment: The real question is, did you change GameScene.sks to IntroScene.sks

Comment: No I did not, didn't realize that mattered? I'll give that a try now.

Comment: That is your scene archived file

Comment: Wow that worked, feel free to post that as the answer and I'll gladly accept KnigtOfDragon. Sorry for being so stupid. So I assume the sks file is required for the initial scene or every scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rename your GameScene.sks to IntroScene.sks

The sks file is an archived file for your scene data,  if you open it up, you will notice you can change a lot of things about the scene, and even add nodes and sprites directly to it.  When you call `if let scene = IntroScene(fileNamed:"IntroScene") {` you are unarchiving the sks file to be loaded as a scene,  so anytime you want to create a new scene, remember that you will need this file.